# How can I move back to Element 0 in an array to reset a loop?

Tags: arrays, animation, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have an array that loops through a bunch of images to make an animation but will change to another array animation once a condition is met. After that array is over, it does return to the first. However, it picks up where it left off instead of resetting.  I need it to return at Element 0 each time.  Any ideas?

```
private var csScript : Main;

var textures : Texture[];
var changeInterval : float = 0.33;
var textures2 : Texture[];
var changeMe : boolean = false;

function Awake() {
    //Get the CSharp Script
    csScript = this.GetComponent("Main");
    //Don't forget to place the 'CSharp1' file inside the 'Standard Assets' folder
}

function Update() {
    if( textures.length == 0 ) // nothing if no textures
        return;
    // we want this texture index now
    var index : int = Time.time / changeInterval;
    var index2 : int = Time.time / changeInterval;
    // take a modulo with size so that animation repeats
    if(csScript.janneleIsWaiting) {
        index = index % textures.length;
        // assign it
        renderer.material.mainTexture = textures[index];
    }

    if(csScript.janelleWorried) {
        print("so so worried");
        index2 = index2 % textures2.length;
        // assign it
        renderer.material.mainTexture = textures2[index2];
        reset();
    }
}

function reset() {
    yield WaitForSeconds(.35);
    csScript.janneleIsWaiting = true;
    csScript.janelleWorried = false;
    csScript.janelleHappy = false;
}
```

Comment: Completely (well, kinda) off-topic, but why wouldn't you want to use Unity's AMAZING animation engine and animation state machine? I admit there was a bit of a learning curve, but once mastered, it's, quite frankly, brilliant.

Comment: @Rajesh: You know that putting unityscript in code-snippets (Only for HTML+CSS+JS) instead of code-blocks is flat-out wrong?

Comment: @LokiSinclair I animated everything in Flash...I think I just might go back and use the animation editor...I did get a handle on that and it's pretty smooth.

Comment: @Rajesh no I didn't.